# Yeoman web app generator gives a wrong link to find bootstrap glyphicon

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, yeoman-generator

I found that when I try to run grunt inside the project generated by yeoman web-generator, it did copy the glyphicon fonts to `bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/fonts/bootstrap/`, however from the main.css file, 

I saw that all the reference link is `/bower_components/...` instead of `../bower_components/...`

After I modify the link to `../` format, it successful find the icons again.

I can't believe it's a bug, because it's so obviously problem that everyone using it will encountered, anyone face the same issue of me? and is there a solved method for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to remove the root options in the `cssmin` task, and/or edit the `$icon-font-path`
variable in your `main.scss`.

Here is the relatives [Github issue](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/645) and [another one](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/issues/149).

Comment: It's not working, the new yeoman generator not using cssmin task, it using usemin task with css: ['<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'], and even I change sass file, it still gives me an absolute link, but just not working.

Comment: And what about a copy task to move the font in the correct directory ?

Comment: edit main.scss will works, because the generator didn't copy the right fonts file, after add an copy task, it works, and thanks, BTW, although the new version of yeoman web app generator comment cssmin, i still need to uncomment it and comment the concat from default build, otherwise it will ignore my custom part of css in sass file, I don't know why.